# Unable to show Firebase document data in datagridview in C# Winforms application

Tags: c#, .net, firebase, winforms, google-cloud-firestore

Here is the class to which I convert the document data:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Google.Cloud.Firestore;

namespace FYP_Desktop
{
    [FirestoreData]
    public class InitialPayment
    {
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string PurchaseOrder { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string PurchaseAmount { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string PackingDepartment { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string CustomerStatus { get; set; }
        [FirestoreProperty]
        public string PaymentPercentile { get; set; }
    }
}
```

The problem I am having is that I get empty rows on the UI even though the firebase collection contains the documents.

Here is the snippet where I try to bind the incoming data with datagridview:

```
CollectionReference coll = conn.db.Collection("payments");
FirestoreChangeListener listener = coll.Listen(
            snapshot =>
            {
                // this clear function clears the data grid view
                // by this, we are able to eliminate the duplicate data binding in the data grid view
                dgvPayments.Rows.Clear();
                foreach (DocumentSnapshot docs in snapshot.Documents)
                {
                    InitialPayment payment = docs.ConvertTo<InitialPayment>();
                    dgvPayments.Rows.Add(payment.PurchaseOrder, payment.PurchaseAmount, payment.PackingDepartment,
                        payment.CustomerStatus, payment.PaymentPercentile);
                }
               
            }
        );
```

Debugging the snippet using a breakpoint also shows that values are null even though I have documents in the collection in Firebase:

[image]

Comment: You my well have documents, however, it appears they all may have null properties. So it seems clear that a closer look at what… `docs.ConvertTo<InitialPayment>();` … returns may be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more efforts, I was able to resolve the issue by making the document field names and InitialPayment's property names identical. Doing so fetched the data properly.